# Why does the linux man page have descriptions of C code?

Tags: c, linux, manpage

Why does the Linux man pages have information for `C` functions, that are not part of the kernel's API? For instance, [`strsep`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html)

Sure, it's useful to provide this functionality, but from a modular perspective, it seems like this should be managed/imported from ANSI.

Comment: Because people write code using other functions than the system calls and need to know how to use them too.  And the manual pages for standard C won't cover the extensions and functions that are not in standard C, and Linux has a lot of those.  The manual pages for standard C functions are usually closely based on the standard C specification.

Comment: The question is probably off-topic here, but I guess the reason is that in 1971 when the pages were originally written, C and unix were closely related.

Comment: Because man pages are the standard way to document commands, functions, files, etc. on Unixy systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux, Unix, and POSIX manual pages document the Linux, Unix, and POSIX systems. A system is a set of things (in these cases, many things) that work together. They do not just document the kernel part of the operating system. They document commands for users, commands for programmers, utilities for system administrators, routines in libraries for programs, system calls for making requests of the operating system, and other features of the entire system.

When the manual pages were started, there was no C standard from ANSI, ISO, or IEC, and so it would not have been possible to defer to those organizations. Further, many of the routines provided by these systems specify behaviors beyond those of the same routines in the C standard library.